# tqdm inside a thread inside Docker doesn't show progress bar

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, progress-bar, tqdm

From inside a Docker container, it seems that `tqdm` is having some trouble showing up when run on its own thread.

I tried other progress bars (eg. `alive-progress`), but they all fail. The same code works flawlessly when ran *outside* of the container. It seems a Docker-specific issue, most likely a `docker-compose` one, but I cannot spot the problem. Any tip?

Edit: `docker run -it console_test` **works**. It's definitely a problem in the configuration of `docker-compose.yml`.

Steps to reproduce:

`console_test/console.py`:

```py
import threading
import time
import tqdm
import sys

print("Starting the test")


def job():
    for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(50)):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.flush()  # this has no effect
        # print("Hi")  # this is printed though!
    print("Finished.")


job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job)
job_thread.start()

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

`console_test/Dockerfile`:

```
# Using official python runtime base image
FROM python:3.8.9

RUN pip install tqdm

COPY . .

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1  # removing this has no effect
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8  # removing this has no effect

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "console.py"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
    console_test:
        build: ./console_test
        stdin_open: true # docker run -i // removing it has no effect
        tty: true        # docker run -t // removing it has no effect
```

And I run the whole thing like this:

```
docker-compose up --build console_test
```

During the for-loop, the bar is not shown. After it finishes and `print` is called, this is the result:

```
Attaching to rotonda_console_test_1
console_test_1   | Starting the test
100% 50/50 [00:05<00:00,  9.97it/s]
console_test_1   | Finished.
```

**EDIT**

Partial solution:

Following [this](http://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/771), I discovered that `docker-compose run` instead of `up` seems to fix the issue. No idea why though.

Comment: Have you tried running directly `docker run -it ...`? What is the result?

Comment: @eagr Great point. It works indeed! As I suspected, it's definitely a docker-compose problem. Editing the original question with this detail.
EDIT: Following this [1], `docker-compose run` instead of `up` seems to fix the issue. No idea why. 
[1]: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/771